# how to make the array print unique in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, duplicates

I am making a shopping cart using PHP. I have two pages:

```
pageA.php
pageB.php
```

The pageA.php fetches data from Database and stores the values in the `$_SESSION` as:

```
$_SESSION['item']
$_SESSION['price']
$_SESSION['size'];
```

and the amount is entered in a FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="pageB.php">
<input ....>
```

and now in the pageB.php I have created an array:

```
$cur_name = $_SESSION['name'];
$cur_price = $_SESSION['price'];
$cur_size = $_SESSION['size'];

$_SESSION['list'][] = array('name' => $cur_name, 'price',$cur_price,'size'=>$cur_size);
```

and printing by using `foreach`...

```
foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as  $key => $items)
     {
         print "<tr>";
         print "<td>".$items['name']."</td>";
         print "<td>".$items['price']."</td>";
         print "<td>".$items['size']."</td>";
         print "</tr>";
     }
```

and the problems start here:

The already listed items will be listed again as a separate item whereas I only want to list unique items and update the amount captured by the input form.

the output looks like this:

```
milk   $2    3L
bread  $3.5  500g
milk   $2    3L
....
```

how do I avoid the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicate elements

Comment: the problem is not the duplicate elements of the array it is the print output that the arry has produced in a session